# Setting a new line from API call not creating newline

Tags: android, api, android-json

Setting a new line without a network call works for me:

`mTextView.setText("Message 1 \nMessage 2");`

[image]

However when I set the text from the JSON in an API call it doesn't work for me:

`mTextView.setText(userInfo.getDescription());`

[image]

The format it's stored in my db is: `hello \nTest message.`

What is the issue?

Edit:

Tried doing this, but doesn't work either

```
Log.d(TAG, "formatDescription: Description: " + description);
String x = description.replace("\n", System.lineSeparator());
Log.d(TAG, "formatDescription: Formatted: " + x);
return x;
```

[image]

Edit 2:

Need to add an extra `"\"` to `.replace("\n", System.lineSeparator());` for it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String description = userInfo.getDescription();
description = description.replace("\\n", System.lineSeparator());
System.out.println(description);
mTextView.setText(description);
```

Comment: Have you checked value of x here? What is that?

Comment: Adding an extra "\" to "\n" works. ```.replace("\\n"```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String desc = userInfo.getDescription().replaceAll("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```